# TypeScript: How to write definition when I extend a module?

Tags: typescript, chai

I extend Chai with a helper in my TypeScript test.

```
import * as chai from 'chai';

chai.use((_chai) => {
  let Assertion = _chai.Assertion;
  Assertion.addMethod('sortedBy', function(property) {
    // ...
  });
});

const expect = chai.expect;
```

In the same file test case makes use of this method:

```
expect(tasks).to.have.been.sortedBy('from');
```

Compiler gives error that "Property 'sortedBy' does not exist on type 'Assertion'".

How can I add declaration of `sortedBy` to `Chai.Assertion`?

I've tried to add module declaration, just like other Chai plugin modules do, but it doesn't work.

```
declare module Chai {
  interface Assertion {
    sortedBy(property: string): void;
  }
}
```

I don't want to make the helper an individual module, because it's trivial.

Comment: @DanRevah I'm using tsd. My question is how to define my extension to the module. The method 'sortedBy' is not included in chai typings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following:

Extend chai in the chaiExt.ts like this:

```
declare module Chai 
{
    export interface Assertion 
    {
        sortedBy(property: string): void;
    }
}
```

Consume in chaiConsumer.ts:

```
import * as chai from 'chai';
//...
chai.expect(tasks).to.have.been.sortedBy('from');
```

[EDIT]

If you are using 'import' - you turn your file into the external module and declaration merging is not supported: [link](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2821)

Comment: I know this way works. But I'm looking for a way to extend and declare it just in-place in my test file.

Comment: If you will use 'import' - you turn your file into the external module and declaration merging is not supported there: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2821

Comment: Thanks. The link explains why my declaration does't work. Let me spend more time to look into it.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct. Modules and interfaces are opened by default on TS so you can redeclare and augment them.

Generally, what I do in cases like this is: I create a globals.d.ts file in the same folder as my project so the .d.ts will be automatically loaded, and then I'd add the type definition as you did.

```
declare module Chai {
  interface Assertion {
    sortedBy(property: string): void;
  }
}
```